# Can't install mysql 5.6 on elementaryos

Tags: mysql, linux

I need LAMP on my elementaryos. I already have php, apache, and phpmyadmin.

Mysql has proven to be a problem to me. I've successfully installed `mysql 5.7`. Unfortunately, the people at mysql decided to add silly changes such as not being able to `mysql -uroot -proot` without `sudo`. Because of this change, I can't login via `phpadmin` with root.

So I've decided to just install `mysql 5.6`.

I've been following [this guide.](https://makandracards.com/makandra/39899-install-mysql-5-6-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Sadly, when I do `apt-cache policy mysql-server`, this is what I get:

```
mysql-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Version table:
     5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
        500 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages
     5.7.21-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
```

The version is 5.7. So now the guide says check `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list`. But this is what I have in there:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out entries below, but any other modifications may be lost.
# Use command 'dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config' as root for modifications.
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt//ubuntu/ wily mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt//ubuntu/ wily mysql-5.6

deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt//ubuntu/ wily mysql-tools
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt//ubuntu/ wily mysql-5.6
```

So it's actually correct. But it's still not `5.6`.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

1.In Software & Updates/Other Software added 14.04 repository:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

2.Installed mysql client and server:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server-5.6
sudo apt install mysql-client-5.6
```

Update: Before installing 5.6, make sure that no other mysql packages are present:

`dpkg -l | grep mysql` - returns list of mysql packages.

Use `apt-get purge <package name>` to purge them.

Source: [16.04 upgrade broke mysql-server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server/760886#760886)